# Bresenham Lines Drawing Alogrithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bresenham

There Is Something In Bresenham's Floating Point Algorithm which annoying me.

The Algorithm is listed below :

```
void line(x0, x1, y0, y1)
{
  int deltax = x1 - x0;
  int deltay = y1 - y0;
  float error = 0;
  float deltaerr = Math.abs((float)deltay / (float)deltax);
  int y = y0

  for(int x=x0;x<=x1;x++)
  {
    SetPixel(x,y)
    error = error + deltaerr
    if (error >= 0.5)
    {
             y = y + 1
             error = error - 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose We Want to Draw **Y=0.6X**. 
So In the first step for x=0 : error will be set as 0.6 and we will run into if statement and y
will increases. and error will be set to -0.4. how can the -0.4 will help us in next step?

So My problem is with this line of code :

```
error = error - 1.0
```

Why we should decease error by 1 ? I have read we do this because of readjustment ! how it can help us ?

Comment: Did you have a look at [the real algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#Algorithm)? Because the one you're showing is only partially correct

Comment: so why the wikipedia puts that on it's top of the page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error is accumulated. When it is greater than half a pixel, the line is moved one pixel over, and the error must then be corrected, again by a whole pixel.

If you simply zero'd the error out, you would only have cancelled out part of the error, and thus the line will step again prematurely and would be the wrong gradient.

In your example for y = 0.6x, if you calculate the error but zero it out, the following happens:

```
error = 0;
plot pixel;
increment error. error = 0.6;
error > 0.5, so move over and reset error to 0;
plot pixel;
increment error. error = 0.6;
error > 0.5, so move over and reset error to 0;
plot pixel;
increment error. error = 0.6;
error > 0.5, so move over and reset error to 0;
...
```

So the line actually has a gradient of 1; Indeed any line with a gradient >= 0.5 will come out the same, which is obviously not very useful.

If you do it correctly:

```
error = 0;
plot pixel;
increment error. error = 0.6;
error > 0.5, so move over and subtract one; error = -0.4;
plot pixel;
increment error. error = 0.2;
plot pixel;
increment error. error = 0.8;
error > 0.5, so move over and subtract one; error = -0.2;
...
```

The line has the correct gradient, because the error is acting as the fractional part of a fixed-point calculation.

Comment: thanks for ur explanation , but is there a reason for choosing 1 for subtracting ? why not 0.5 ?

Comment: That's in the explanation above. The error represents the fractional part of a pixel. When you move over 1 pixel, you must subtract 1 from the error.

Answer (score 0):

`error` is `ideal_y-current_y`

When we entered into a next iteration of the loop we increased `x` without touching `y`. `error=error+deltaerr` is update of `error` after this operation.

If we decided to increment `y`, we again must update `error`, that's what `error=error-1` is.

Comment: I have noted that we should re adjust the error , My Question is that why e=e-1 , why not e=0 ?

Comment: do u mean error=error+deltaerr will set error to ideal y for current x ?

Comment: because ideal_y may not be an integer, while current_y always is, so error may not be zero even after correction

Comment: error=error+deltaerr will set error to ideal error after x++, error=error-1 will set error to ideal error after y++

Comment: Because e might not be zero after subracting.

Comment: this is actually what error should be - difference between ideal_y and y, after modification of x or y ideal error changes, so we set this value to variable "error"